# How to test if component hast only the allowed props and uses only the allowed classes with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine, react-testing-library

I have a Button component that looks like this:

```
const Button = ({
    children,
    type,
    btnStyles,
    onClick,
}: any) => {
    //...
}

export default Button
```

I wan't to make sure that the button is only used with the allowed props defined above. My test currently looks like this:

```
it('should only have the allowed props', () => {
    const tree = shallow(
        <Button
            type='button'
            buttonStyles='a-custom-button'
            onClick={() => {
                console.log('Custom Button Clicked')
            }}
        >
            <i></i>
            Button
        </Button>
    )

    expect(tree.prop('type')).toBeDefined()
    expect(tree.prop('buttonStyles')).toBeDefined()
})
```

I also want to make sure that only allowed class names can be used for buttonStyles. For example  the button can only contain the classes `.a-custom-button` and `.a-custom-button-styles`.

How can I do this with Jest?

Comment: You won't need to test for it if you provide correct prop types instead of any.

Answer (score 0):

@Clarity is correct. You're using TypeScript so you could use a union of valid class names:

```js
type ButtonProps = {
  btnStyles: 'a-custom-button' | 'a-custom-button-styles';
}

const Button = ({
    btnStyles,
}: ButtonProps) => {
   console.log(btnStyles);
   return null;
}

Button({ btnStyles: 'a-custom-button' })        // works
Button({ btnStyles: 'a-custom-button-styles' }) // also works
Button({ btnStyles: 'invalid-class-name' })     // doesn't work - invalid prop value in TypeScript
```

Playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrsYB7AdgBQE5LAZygXigG8AoKKAI2BQGVQAbCHALigHIBDAWgGM4dkAWy4UEyFGygAfdtz4Ckw0YlRcBIRjjYBuEgF8SJHqgGwxqAlAAUpcuSq0GTADT7W8Feiy4AlAQB8xGTkxig4SIwAdPRIAOZWDnQaTD66dhgQwHAYKFAocPT0ugYkHuI2lNRJmqycvPxCIuYSUHp+dh0A9J1QAO5IGADWOKXNFYlOLLL1CkrNapOSbVDdUBz04X0Dw6Oe41WTtQCWKABu60cAJrz0HDg4XCgcghBL7XarJ+f0V1Bg3lBvnBoAAVcAQGg8DBHMDAKAQDBYDAkIA